# What are the most optimal permissions for /bin/su?

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat, sudo, su

I want users to be able to use "sudo su -", but not to switch user by password.

What are the most optimal permissions for /bin/su?

Right now it's:

```
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 42436 Jul 26 18:19 /bin/su
```

I was thinking about changing this to 700, is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a bad idea. You don't need `sudo su -`, teach your users to do `sudo -i` instead. Which means you then don't need `su` and can set up your pam configuration to only allow root to use `su`.

Mucking about with the filesystem permissions of `/bin/su` is then no longer needed, which is good, because any upgrade of `su` would restore them to their defaults.

Comment: interesting the --login (-i) option for su, but it fails on a ipa/Idm environment whereas the sudo su - trick works, I cannot post the whole thing (too little room in a comment, but I get a generic krb5 error). My user has sudo root rights (nopasswd)

Comment: @natxoasenjo That sounds like a separate question.